# Create Stored Proc for Array of Strings in MSSQL

Tags: java, arrays, sql-server-2008

I have Array with three strings. I need to include that into my Stored Procedure.

My Backbean

```
private String [] model_NU= {"'N'", "'U'", "'D'"};
```

My Stored Proc. in Java

```
String stm = "{call myDB.dbo.StoredPorcQuery (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
try {   
        ps = con.prepareStatement(stm);
        ps.setArray(1, fb.getModel_nu());
        --------
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

I'm using MS SQL Server Management Studio and here is the variables in Stored Proc.

```
-----
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[StoredPorcQuery] 
@model_nu varchar (6)='%', ->Not sure here I need to use varchar to represent array
----
WHERE----
table1.model_nu IN (@model_nu)  ->Not sure this part.
```

I am not expert in Stored proc and not sure how to declare this array in Stored Proc and use IN function to query with array values.

Comment: No such thing as an array in SQL Server. Look up TVPs (no idea about whether Java supports them) and if not then use a string splitting function in T-SQL. See http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings and http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql as a start.

Comment: Is there any way I can pass it as a  ps.setString to query with IN parameter?

Comment: You'd have to use dynamic SQL. Why do you think that would be better than splitting the string?

Comment: I am not splitting string, I have values from  select drop down menu that I need to send to Stored Proc. to do the query

Comment: Right, and I'm suggesting that in the stored procedure, you use a string splitting function. Did you read the links I posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the above issue by creating a table function in stored proc. and send my array values to the function before query.

SQL Function (dbo.fnSplitString) to Create table and separate string by ','

```
USE [MYTable]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fnSplitString]    Script Date: 05/08/2015 16:06:21 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

and in Stored Proc use this line

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[StoredPorcQuery] 
@model_nu varchar (10)='%',
----
WHERE----
table1.model_nu  IN (select *from dbo.fnSplitString(@model_nu, ','))
```

and in Java

```
String stm = "{call myDB.dbo.StoredPorcQuery (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
try {   
        ps = con.prepareStatement(stm);
        ps.setString(1, fb.getModel_nu());
        --------
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

and declare Array in Back Beans

```
private String [] model_NU= {"N","U","D"};
```

The function will split the array and store into a table and finally you can send this table to query using stored proc.